# Last entry from group by in select, replace null with last known value

Tags: mysql, join, intervals

My database is in mysql.
There are a couple of things I am trying to achieve. I have two time series data. One records at 15 mins intervals and another one records whenever a change of value happens. I am trying to join these two tables.
The desired table would be 3 columns, {time_stamp, table1.value, table2.value} and same number of rows as table1
1) table1.value just keeps it's value.
2) table2.value column have the last value from table 2 within 15 mins prior from the table1's time_stamp
3) if the table2.value is null, keep the last known value

I have tried to left join the two tables and tried doing "group by" time_stamp and tried to get latest entry from "group by" without success.
I have also tried to replace the null values in the resulting column
"using @n := COALESCE(table2.value,@n)".
I think it didn't work because the joined results weren't in order. I've tried to add order by at the end of query also with no success..

Is this possible to achieve in just one query? Appreciate any help!

table-1

```
+---------------------------------------+
|time                       | value     |
+---------------------------+-----------+
|'2014-09-15 06:15:02.1500' | 71        |
|'2014-09-15 06:30:02.1500' | 72        |
|'2014-09-15 06:45:02.1500' | 73        |
|'2014-09-15 07:00:02.1500' | 74        |
|'2014-09-15 07:15:02.1500' | 75        |
|'2014-09-15 07:30:02.1500' | 76        |
|'2014-09-15 07:45:02.1500' | 77        |
+---------------------------+-----------+
```

table-2

```
+---------------------------------------+
|time                       | value     |
+---------------------------+-----------+
|'2014-09-15 06:14:02.1500' | 30        |
|'2014-09-15 06:15:02.1500' | 55        |
|'2014-09-15 06:18:02.1500' | 60        |
|'2014-09-15 06:20:02.1500' | 62        |
|'2014-09-15 06:23:02.1500' | 35        |
|'2014-09-15 07:36:02.1500' | 45        |
|'2014-09-15 07:38:02.1500' | 36        |
|'2014-09-15 07:40:02.1500' | 87        |
+---------------------------+-----------+
```

result_table

```
+---------------------------------------+----------+
|time                       |table1.val |table2.val|                  
+---------------------------+-----------+----------+
|'2014-09-15 06:15:02.1500' | 71        |30        |
|'2014-09-15 06:30:02.1500' | 72        |35        |
|'2014-09-15 06:45:02.1500' | 73        |35        |
|'2014-09-15 07:00:02.1500' | 74        |35        |
|'2014-09-15 07:15:02.1500' | 75        |35        |
|'2014-09-15 07:30:02.1500' | 76        |35        |
|'2014-09-15 07:45:02.1500' | 77        |87        |
+---------------------------+-----------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use subselect in value list for this:

```
select time, value as t1value,
coalesce(@val := (
    select value from table2
    where time < table1.time
        AND time >= table1.time - INTERVAL 15 MINUTE
    order by time desc limit 1
), @old) as t2value, @old := @val from table1;
```

Comment: I have tried that, The returned value is from looking at the whole table-2 instead of only up until the time stamp.

Comment: There is condition on time < table1.time, order by time and limit. I don't see how that will look at whole table.
edit: I think I get it now...